# Django When does cache expire?

Tags: django

Say you cache a view response with `cache_page(60)` for one minute.

After the view is cached, after 20 seconds someone hit the page again, does the cache expire at time-60 or time-80 (60+20) from the origin (first hit)

Comment: The cache will be invalidated every 60 seconds, regardless of hits.